# Seeking the solution of an equation with quadratic kernel matrix as variable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, quadratic-forms

I tried to solve the following equation in matrix ${\bf A} \in \Bbb R^{N \times N}$.  There are a total of $M$ known vectors.

$$\textbf{x}^{(i)}=(x_1^{(i)},x_2^{(i)},...,x_N^{(i)})^T \in \Bbb R^N,i=1,2,...,M$$

Let a constant vector $$\textbf{d}=(d^{(1)},d^{(2)},...,d^{(M)})^T \in \Bbb R^M$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^M(\textbf{x}^{(i)}(\textbf{x}^{(i)})^T)((\textbf{x}^{(i)})^T\textbf{A}\textbf{x}^{(i)})+M\textbf{A}+\sum_{i=1}^M(\textbf{x}^{(i)}(\textbf{x}^{(i)})^T)\textbf{d}^{(i)}=\textbf{0}$$

Comment: Please do not rely on images. Type your formulas. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You can bold using `{\bf A}`